# Mailchimp PUT always returns a false error so is impossible to check for real errors

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have coded some PHP scripts to create and send a newsletter using MailChimp API. Below the steps 
1) First of all, I update a template with the products I want to include in the newsletter
2)I create a campaign
3)I attach the template content to the campaign
4)I send it

The issue happens when I attach the template content to the campaign. 
If I check for errors before to send the campaign (to double check that the template was attached correctly) 
I always get a timeout error, even if in reality by ignoring that error the campaign is sent without problems.
Obviously, I can't just ignore the error. I want a reliable system to avoid sending empty emails.

Comment: //Attach the campaign to the template
    $result = $MailChimp->put('campaigns/' . $campaignId . '/content', [
   'template' => ['id' => 77
  ]
   ]);
if ($MailChimp->success()) {
 $tempate_attached=1; //proceed with sending the campaign
 
} else {
 echo "ERROR ON ATTACHING THE TEMPLATE : " . $MailChimp->getLastError();
 exit;
}

bool(false) 
Request timed out after 10.001011 seconds.
If I use $MailChimp->getLastResponse() I get the below response